# How to while iterate over a class method?

Tags: python, oop, methods, while-loop, counter

Below is a script for calculating button clicks per minute - as a pilot run for implementing a Hall effect sensor for measuring motor rpms. It does work in a satisfactory manner. However, i would love to implement it in an OOP mode-with class and methods. It is my understanding that classes are rather 'allergic' to while looping with their methods, returning only the last value. Any suggestions will be most appreciated.

```
import keyboard as kb
from time import time

#4 clicks equal 1 rev(olution)/the sampling duration is 5 revs

while (1):
    revs = 0
    t_start = time()
    while revs < 5:
        clicks = 0
        while clicks < 4:
            kb.wait('k')
            clicks += 1
        revs += 1
    t_stop = time()
    dt = t_stop - t_start
    rpm = revs * 60 / dt
    print(rpm)
```

Comment: " It is my understanding that classes are rather 'allergic' to while looping with their methods" - well, no, they probably don't care. Your question is unclear, though, as you don't show us how you would write your code using classes. And a good first question would be: to you need to?

Comment: You are mostly right Thierry. I dont -as a matter of life or death need to. However,  it would be nifty to have a class which counts the rpm of my stepper motor, and be able to call it and run it concurrently with the class that actually modulates the motor.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to do correctly, then the code below should help you. I defined a motor class and made a method inside the class that calculates the rpm and updates the rpm property of the object.

```
class Motor:
     rpm = 0.0

     def calculate_rpm(self):
         revs = 0
         t_start = time()
         while revs < 5:
             clicks = 0
             while clicks < 4:
                 kb.wait('k')
                 clicks += 1
             revs += 1
         t_stop = time()
         dt = t_stop - t_start
         self.rpm = revs * 60 / dt
```

From here, one line `motor.calculate_rpm()` can be placed inside your while loop and will update the value of the rpm property of the motor object every iteration of the while loop. From here you can do whatever you want with that data accessible at motor.rpm.

Don't forget to initialize the motor object with `motor = Motor()`

This is the best I could do with the information you provided.